# How return one dimension list by list comprehension from nested list in list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
a = [
[1, 2],
[1, 2]
]

print([x for x in [x for x in a]])
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

But I want to see something like that:

```
[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

How I cad do this?

Comment: is the depth of the nested list always the same? or can it be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
a = [
[1, 2],
[1, 2]
]

lst = [q for i in a for q in i]
print(lst)
```

The above one is not always working it gives you an error if the list is something like this.

```
a = [[1, 2],[1, 2],2]
```

But this one always work.

```py
a = [
[1, 2],
[1, 2]
]
lst = []
for i in a:
    if type(i) == list:
        lst.extend(i)
    else:
        lst.append(i)
print(lst)
```

Comment: Yep, I just write extra square brackets...

Comment: @Galoperidol Thanks if you don't mind you can vote too.

Comment: @Timus Sorry for that now working

Comment: Just as a reminder from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _"... avoid trying to answer questions which have already been asked and answered many times before."_ This question is easily identified as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
    a = [
[1, 2],
[1, 2]
]
flatten_list = lambda y:[x for a in y for x in flatten_list(a)] if type(y) is list else [y]

print(flatten_list(a))
```